# What is the most efficient way to automate data fetching from smartsheet to excel?

Tags: excel, automation, smartsheet-api

There is not too much data so considering keeping it in an excel workbook, but can also do it with SQL whichever could work better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can download a sheet to a CSV or XLSX file using the `GET /sheets/{sheetId}` endpoint and an `Accept` header as documented here:http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet-as-excel-pdf-csv
Then it's up to you to import into Excel or SQL server.

There is also an ODBC connector: https://www.smartsheet.com/apps/smartsheet-odbc

Comment: The link appears to not be working. Seems interesting. Can you please provide more detail? Which programming language is this?

Comment: Sorry about the bad link - corrected. This is an HTTP/REST API that can be called from any language, or even a shell/command script. We have client SDKs to ease use from C#, Java, Node.js, Python, and Ruby.